# by clicking on input box twice it's printing it's own html code inside input box

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a dynamic table and getting td values from array, my goal was when I click on any cell that convert to input box and get this td value as input value so we can change and when I click on another td the previous td turn back to it's original position with new or same old value.

Now this is almost happening, problem is when I click on td it turn to input box and when I click again on the same input box it prints it's html code inside the text box as it's value and then the all td's go crazy, like this: `<input id='thisInputId' type='text' value='"+thisInHtml+"' style='width: 100px;'>` it creates two input boxes in same time and sometime prints the html code inside td without creating input box. I am new to these things trying to learn and stuck on this for two days.

```
var getInput = ""; var inputsParent = ""; var inputs = ""; var thisInHtml = ""; var getInputVal = "";
   var thisTdInnerHtml = ""; var input = ""; var flag = 1;

    var getInputLength = getInput.length+1;
      for(var j=0; j<allTds.length;j++){         
       allTds[j].onclick = function(){ 
        thisInHtml = this.innerHTML;                 
         var thisId = this.id;                                             

                   if(inputs.length != 0){
                   inputsParent.removeChild(inputs);   
                   inputsParent.innerHTML = getInputVal;     
                   flag = 1;
                    }

                  this.innerHTML = thisInHtml;  
                  if(getInputVal != ""){
                  input = this.innerHTML =  "<input id='thisInputId' type='text' value='"+thisInHtml+"' style='width: 100px;'>";
                  getInput = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
                  getInputVal = document.getElementById("thisInputId").value;
              }

                  if(getInputLength > 0){                      
                   for(var k =0; k<getInputLength;k++){
                     inputsParent = getInput[k].parentNode;
                     inputs = inputsParent.childNodes[0];
            }
         } 
      }            
   }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mohsinali/npckf9xs/6/

Answer (score 0):

After some struggle I came up with the solution on my own and I fix the issue, I also figure it out that it's always simple we just have to think right. It can be more optimize I believe.

```
    var getInput = ""; var inputsParent = ""; var inputs = ""; var thisInHtml = ""; var getInputVal = "";
    var thisTdInnerHtml = ""; var input = ""; var flag = 0; var thisInputVal = ""; var thisTdId = "";   
    var cellIndex = ""; var thisRowIndex = "";

      for(var j=0; j<allTds.length;j++){
       allTds[j].ondblclick = function(){
        thisInHtml = this.innerHTML;                         

            getInput = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

                if(getInput.length === 0){  
                   input = this.innerHTML =  "<input id='thisInputId' type='text' value='"+thisInHtml+"' style='width: 100px;'>";
                    thisTdId = this.id;     
                     cellIndex = this.cellIndex;

                       var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
                         for(var o=0; o<rows.length;o++){
                           rows[o].ondblclick = function(){
                             thisRowIndex = this.rowIndex-1;                      
                      }
                   }                       
                }

                else if(getInput.length > 0){
                for(var k=0; k<getInput.length; k++){
                inputsParent = getInput[k].parentNode;
                inputs = inputsParent.childNodes[0];
                thisInputVal = inputs.value;
                inputsParent.removeChild(inputs);
                flag = 1;

                }
                }

                   if(flag === 1){
                    var getTdById = document.getElementById(thisTdId);
                     getTdById.innerHTML = thisInputVal;

                         if(cellIndex === 0){                    
                         proArr[thisRowIndex] = thisInputVal;
                         }              

                         else if (cellIndex === 1){
                         proColorArr[thisRowIndex] = thisInputVal;
                         }

                         else if (cellIndex === 2){
                         proPriceArr[thisRowIndex] = thisInputVal;
                         }                       

                         flag = 0;                           
                   }
                }
             }
          }
```